# Error en Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular7

Estoy iniciando en angular. Y para eso, uso TypeScript. Al crear el código en sublime text y abrir la consola, me aparece este error:

```
 tsc *.ts
 File "<string>", line 1
 tsc *.ts
     ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Y también si lo intento de esta forma:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> tsc .\app.ts
File "<string>", line 1
tsc .\app.ts
           ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Este el es app.ts:

```
alert("Hola, mundo.");
```

Y este el HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Primera p&aacute;gina con Angular.</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./script/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Comment: muestra el app.js

Comment: El app.js no existe. Según lo que he visto, al realizar el tsc, debería crearlo automáticamente, ¿no?

Comment: no, el app.js es el archivo principal si lo hiciste con scalfolding debe estar si estas haciendo todo de forma manual debes crearlo, te recomiendo que estudies primero typescript.

Comment: En realidad, no uso nada de eso. Soy realmente nuevo y no tengo idea. Ya cree el app.js, pero la consola sigue el error.

Comment: no te preocupes alguna vez todos fuimos principiantes en algo, lo primero es buscar ayuda de los creadores y para eso esta el sitio de angular. https://angular.io/start ten en cuenta que angularjs no es lo mismo que angular, desde la version 2 se conoce como angular solo y trabaja con typescript que es un superset de javascript. sigue el enlace que te coloque antes y de seguro que entenderas mejor.